# Jade template are not display page as expected

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

I use Node.js & express and for the view I use Jade template ,
What I want is that the **Test text** will be on the bottom under the black navigation bar and currently I was not able to do so(it's hiding under the black navbar how can I move it to the bottom ),what I miss here ? 
I put the div

This is the code for jade -Layout.jade

```
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
        script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
    body 
          nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
           .container
              .navbar-header
                button.navbar-toggle(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1')
                      spansronly
                      span.icon-bar
                      span.icon-bar
                      span.icon-bar
               #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
              ul.nav.navbar-nav
                li
                  a(href='/recipes/bbq')  Tab1
                li
                  a(href='/recipes/bbq')  Tab2
            div.container
                block content
```

This is the content 
extends layout

extends layout

block content
    .jumbtroon
        h1= 'Test'

I put the div.container in the same indetation of the first div

this is the rendered HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

            Arrivals

        </title>
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse">
                            <spansronly></spansronly>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/recipes/bbq">

                                     Tab1

                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/recipes/bbq">

                                     Tab2

                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbtroon">
                <h1>

                    test

                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here in the img you can see that the test is under the navbar**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the navbar floats on top of the page, the rest of the page's content starts under it . Bootstraps documentation has a solution for this, see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top.

Add some padding to the top of the page by adding:

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

to your custom.css file

Comment: I use node.js and in the public folder I've added only the bootstrap.min.css file,where should I put your suggested code?

Comment: Add a custom.css file to your public folder and include it in the same way as the bootstrap.min.css file. Make sure you include it after the bootstrap file. You can use this file to add your own custom styles

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy,voted up,one last question :) when I use jumbotroon theame there is gray area in the middle of the page,how should I put my title and list item in this area,Currently I dont see it at all...

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo, I see `jumbtroon` instead of `jumbotron` in your html

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response buddy, I still dont see the gray area (after fix typo)for the jumbotroon at all in the screen maybe I miss something basic..., can you assist please?

Comment: I'm really not sure why you don't see the grey area, if I copy the html from your question, get the bootstrap files from a cdn (see external resources), fix the type and add the `padding-top: 70px` it looks good I think. See http://jsfiddle.net/ckuijjer/jLv3Lfy6/ or the screenshot in http://imgur.com/0AKg4TE. I'm afraid I can't help you any further

Comment: One last question...when I do inspect element and click on the jumbotroon element I see  rectangle in the middle of the screen but it's clear (same background color )There is a way maybe to change this color explicit?or maybe I miss some reference?

Comment: If, in my jsFiddle, you can't see the difference between the grey area and the background perhaps the brightness of your screen is really high. I've updated my jsFiddle to give it a pink background color.

Comment: Thanks I see that (also the gray), I took the css and add it to my css (where i put the padding-top70 which is work ) and nothing happen?any idea what can be missing ?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the html is different, or that the bootstrap css isn't loaded properly, sorry :(

Comment: Mark it as solved,Thanks!just other question do you know how can I change the size of list item text ?

Comment: With `font-size` you can set the font-size used, for example `li { font-size: 18px; }` would set it to 18px for all list items.